# PHP Switch and adding content to one variable

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement

I'm using this function:

```
function makeImmunities($data) {
    $immunities = explode(',', $data);
    foreach($immunities as $immunity) {
        switch($immunity) {
            case 'poison':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
            break;
            case 'earth':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
            break;
            case 'paralyze':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/paralyze.gif"/> ';
            break;
            case 'death':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/death.gif"/> ';
            break;
            case 'ice':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/ice.gif"/> ';
            break;
            case 'invisible':
                $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/invisible.gif"/> ';
            break;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

And $ret has .=, so content should be added to itself. But it doesn't.
I wan't it to work this way:

$data has an array which looks like this : 'poison', 'earth', 'death'.
And this function returns only first case:

> `$ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';`

I wan't it too add ALL of the content that $ret has if case is the same as the $immunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most extensible and easiest I can find (without an if or even a loop)

```
function makeImmunities($data) {

   $allImmunities = array(
     'poison' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
     'earth' => '/images/gems/earth.gif',
     'paralyze' => '/images/gems/paralyze.gif',
     'death' => '/images/gems/death.gif',
     'ice' => '/images/gems/ice.gif',
     'invisible' => '/images/gems/invisible.gif',
   );

   $immunities = array_intersect_key($allImmunities, array_flip(explode(',', str_replace(' ','',$data))));

   return implode(' ', array_map(function(&$item, $key) {
      return "<img src=\"{$item}\" alt=\"{$key}\" />";
   }, $immunities, array_keys($immunities)));
}
```

**Exemple:**

```
var_export(makeImmunities('ice,poison,death'));
```

Output

```
'<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif" alt="poison" /> <img src="/images/gems/death.gif" alt="death" /> <img src="/images/gems/ice.gif" alt="ice" />'
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch doesn't work like that you will need to use an `if` and do something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'poison' => '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ',
    'earth'  => '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> '
    'etc'    => '...'
);

if(isset($options[$immunity])){
    $ret .= $options[$immunity];
}
```

Comment: Of course the switch works like that. You didn't understand the question, did you? ;)

Comment: @jacek switch may work like that, but regardless this is a superior solution to using switch.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that `$data` contains an array, but from the code it is clear, that it should contain the string, for example `$data='earth,ice,poison';`. Notice, that there mustn't be any space. By the way, it is good to initialize (with empty string) the `$ret` variable before foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
$immunities = explode(',', $data);
foreach($imminities as $key => $value) {
    $ret .= "<img src='/images/gems/{$value}.gif" />";
}
return $ret;
```

You'll have to check for the immunities though. You could easily add a if clause to inside the foreach, something like

```
if($value == "earth" || $value == "water" ....)
```

Pretty simple way to do it.

**Update** As suggested by Cole, the part inside the if condition could be replaced with a `in_array($value, $immunities_supported)`. I don't know about the efficiency of this though.
Remember you also have to add a `$immunities_supported = array("earth", "water");` etc with the immunities that are present.
(The code below by Cole doesn't work directly though, it's just a concept, since $value is *always* in $immunities)

Comment: For the latter, you could do `if(in_array($value,$immunities))`.

Comment: Oh right. Though, I try to avoid in_array and these looping things as much as possible, because if $immunities becomes large, an in_array would potentially use a lot of resources. Though that huge if might also use it... Eh. Weak argument, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to initialize your "$ret" variable, add "$ret='';" before the "foreach" loop. Use if and elseif.

Comment: You don't need to initalize the `$ret`. You should, but you don't have to - foreach doesn't have its own scope, so the variable is created in the first iteration and it is persistent.

Comment: @jacek If you want to code correctly, you need it. But if you want to make dirty codes, as it seem to be your case, you don't need it, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

function makeImmunities($data) {

```
$ret = ""; //initialise $ret

$immunities = explode(',', $data);

foreach($immunities as $immunity) {

    switch($immunity) {
        case 'poison':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'earth':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'paralyze':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/paralyze.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'death':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/death.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'ice':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/ice.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'invisible':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/invisible.gif"/> ';
        break;
    }
    /*
     * creates an array $match with key = immunity of match found e.g poison, death, earth
     * and values equal to <img src="/images/gems/xxxxxx.gif"/> where xxxxxx is the 
     * value for each corresponding image tag. 
     */
    $match[$immunity] = $ret; 
}
return $match;
```

}

$input = 'poison, earth, death';

$ans =  makeImmunities($input); // returns an array

print_r($ans); //prints the array

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeImmunities($data) {

$ret = ""; //initialise $ret

$immunities = explode(',', $data);  
foreach($immunities as $immunity) {

    switch($immunity) {
        case 'poison':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'earth':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/earth.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'paralyze':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/paralyze.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'death':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/death.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'ice':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/ice.gif"/> ';
        break;
        case 'invisible':
            $ret .= '<img src="/images/gems/invisible.gif"/> ';
        break;
    }

    $match[$immunity] = $ret; 
}
return $match;
```

}

Comment: this modified function accepts data in form of $data = 'poison, death, earth'; i.e a string separated by ',' then it returns an array. so you can use print_r() to print it or treat the returned value as array.